# Sum all column values in a 2d array to produce an associative 1d array of totals

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum

I want to sum entries to an array (dynamic array, data being taken from the database) and return sum of each entry. The multidimensional array has the following shape:

```
<?php
$sample = array(
    "term_1_mid" => array(
        "English" => 56,
        "Mathematics" => 34,
        "Creative Arts" => 87
    ),
    "term_1_end" => array(
        "English" => 67,
        "Mathematics" => 59,
        "Creative Arts" => 95
    )
);
```

What I want to do is add the values of the sample array in "term_1_mid" to the values of the same sample array in "term_1_end"... So the resulting summation output should be something like:

```
<?php
$result = array(
    "English" => 123, // 56 + 67 from above
    "Mathematics" => 93, // 34 + 59
    "Creative Arts" => 182 // 87 + 95
);
```

Is there any way I could achieve this?

I tried the following code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<?php
$final_score = [];

array_push($final_score, array_map(function($arr, $arr1) {
return $arr + $arr1;
}, $sample["term_1_mid"], $sample["term_1_end"]));

print_r($final_score);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code you have already tried that is not working as expected.

Comment: I have added the code I was working on but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution for the problem.

```
    <?php
    $sample = array(
          "term_1_mid" => array(
               "English" => 56,
               "Mathematics" => 34,
               "Creative Arts" => 87),
          "terrm_1_end" => array(
               "English" => 67,
               "Mathematics" => 59,
               "Creative Arts" => 95)
          );

     # Initializing array to store the result
     $output_array = array();

     # Loop for adding the values
     foreach($sample as $sample_key => $sample_value){
         foreach ($sample_value as $key => $value){
             $output_array[$key] += $value;
         }
     }

     # To check the data in array
     foreach($output_array as $key => $value){
         # used br tag only to show the each values in each line
         echo $key . " => ". $value . "<br>";
     }
     ?>
```

Output :

```
English => 123
Mathematics => 93
Creative Arts => 182
```

Comment: While the answer below also works the same way as this, I'll mark this as the answer essentially because it came first... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is [a demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e407016a75e5ed6ea4c01dc0d97c78d95c2fbe8d).

```
$sample = array(
"term_1_mid" => array(
"English" => 56,
"Mathematics" => 34,
"Creative Arts" => 87),
"terrm_1_end" => array(
"English" => 67,
"Mathematics" => 59,
"Creative Arts" => 95)
);

$arrSum =[];
foreach($sample as $term=>$termname){
    foreach($termname as $sub=>$mark){
        if(!isset($arrSum[$sub])){$arrSum[$sub] = 0;}
        $arrSum[$sub] += $mark;
    }
}
print_r($arrSum);
```

Comment: how and why does this work? Please **edit your answer** and let us all know, cheers!

Comment: @Martin Thank you for your response shared for good one updated.

Comment: @vadivela: I think Martin was asking if you could edit this answer with an English explanation of how it works (or why it solves the question). Talking the reader through it can be very educational for future readers.